# How to change top and bottom padding of text in MaterialDesign Overlined Textfield in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, material-design

I'm trying to change padding top and padding bottom of text in material design text field.

I already try to apply shape and typography schemes but it had no effect.

[image: textfield with default padding]

This is my code:

```swift
// Outlet
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: MDCTextField!

// Implementation
nameTextField.placeholder = "Nome"
nameTextField.delegate = self
let nameTextFieldController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: nameTextField)
```

How can i change these spaces?

**** UPDATE ****

After change textRect by overiding MDCTextField i achieve following result. That is a a great advance. But how can i change the size of border to match text?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you can extend the `MDCTextField` class, then override this method:

```
        override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect { 
         return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)) 
        }
```

Change `top` and `bottom` values as you wish.

If you cannot access/modify or extend the `MDCTextField` class, or if it already has its `textRect(:forBounds)` implementation, you can create your own UITextField class such as:

```
       class MyTextField: UITextField{
           ...
       }
```

> ***NOTE:*** You can even try to inherit `MDCTextField` class:

```
       class MyTextField: MDCTextField{
           ...
       }
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your answer. I could achieve the text position, but now i need to reduce the height of border to match with text size. I updated the post to show my result. Do you know what can i do to resize the height of border? Thanks!

Comment: When you say "height of border", do you mean thickness ?
If so, try `nameTextField.layer.borderWidth = 4`, or other values. If my answer helped you, please give a feedback

Comment: Hi Andrew, i mean the space between text and border. Do you know how can i change it?

Comment: Did `textRect` work for you ? If so, try to change `top` and `bottom` `edgeInsets`